# Pinging two PCs and trying to capture ICMPs with third PC

Tags: networking, ping, tcpdump, wireshark, tshark

I have a setup of three computers that are all on the same subnet and connected to a switch. All services are reachable. I'm pinging from PC(1) to PC(2). Opening tshark with PC(3) but cannot see packages that are not destined (or have the source) for PC(3).

All kinds of capturing software like Wireshark, tcpdump, tshark, etc., even in promiscuous mode, just cannot see traffic that is not destined for the capturing host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible unless either:

1. All three machines are plugged into a [network hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_hub) rather than a [network switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch).  I don't know if hubs are even made any more (I don't think I've even seen one since the 1990s), but the difference is that:

   - with a hub (also known as a "repeater"), ALL packets on the network are sent to all ports on the hub.  This obviously doesn't scale well if there are many devices on the network.
   - a switch maintains a table of which devices (i.e. their MAC Addresses) are connected to which ports, so only "broadcast" packets (e.g. discovery packets like ARP WHO-HAS, DHCPDISCOVER, as well as packets to the network's broadcast address) are sent to all ports - once a switch has discovered which port a device is connected to, then packets for that destination are only sent to the that port.
2. You have configured one of the ports on the switch to be in "promiscuous" mode (also known as "port mirroring"), so that it gets all packets on the network.  This typically requires some kind of "smart" or managed switch, one that either has a serial console port or http/https, telnet, or ssh access to configure it.

   Note that most cheap home/small business switches are un-managed and can not be configured.  Some router/switch combination devices (e.g. an [xDSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line) "modem" with multiple LAN ports) sometimes have some basic port configuration capability.
3. The machine you want to do the packet sniffing on has two network interfaces (each one directly connected to one of the other two machines) and acts as a bridge or router between the two network segments.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not mention specialized equipment, I assume you are using a standard switch to connect these PCs. Normal switches use a MAC address table. It basically is a mapping of "PC identified via MAC → port (the physical connector)". This way, the switch can send unicast packages to the correct port. PCs on other ports do not receive the packages. Only packages with unknown destinations or broadcast packages will be output to all ports. This not only helps with privacy, but also boosts performance since reduces overall traffic.

What you want to do is called "sniffing". There are various ways to to this, see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/72855/sniffing-on-a-switched-lan). For academic purposes, if you happen to have a system with two network cards, you can create a bridge and connect both PCs to the third one. This way, you can monitor the traffic, too.